# The anomaly of y value of Lagrange interpolation realized by matlab

Tags: matlab

## Want to use matlab to achieve lagrange interpolation.The original data **x=[0 3 5 7 9 11 12 13 14 15],y=[0 1.2 1.7 2.0 2.1 2.0 1.8 1.2 1.0 1.6]**.My code is as follows:

```
    clear;
    clc;
    x1 = [0 3 5 7 9 11 12 13 14 15];
    y1 = [0 1.2 1.7 2.0 2.1 2.0 1.8 1.2 1.0 1.6];
    n = length(x1);
    syms x;

    for i=1:n
        t = x1;
        t(i) = [];
        L(i) = prod((x-t)./(x1(i)-t));
    end

    u = sum(L.*y1);
    p = simplify(u);
    xx=0:0.1:15;
    yy = subs(p,x,xx);
    [min_y,ind] = min(yy(xx>=13 & xx<=15));
    xx_range = xx(xx>=13 & xx<=15);     
    min_x = xx_range(ind);               

    plot(x1,y1,'bo',xx,yy,'--',min_x,min_y,'rx');
    grid on
    k_0 = vpa(subs(diff(p,x),x,0),10);
```

The image drawn is as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRoUq.png)

**My question is why is the y value negative in the range of x from 0 to 3**
I admit that it is not appropriate to use Lagrange interpolation to process multiple data,though the number of data is not too big and the deviation around zero was so large that I wondered if there was something wrong with my algorithm.

I'm always grateful for any help!

Comment: That is completely normal behaviour when using Lagrange interpolation. Check [Runge's phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%27s_phenomenon) to see that increasing the degree of the polynomial does not always improve accuracy.